# Displaying Yandex mapView on viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, yandex-maps

I already have API key from yandex. I have already downloaded and run the project from https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-ios. I created Settings.h/Settings.m files in my project and used this code to display mapView.

```
[[Settings sharedSettings] setApiKey: @"My API Key"];
self.mapView = [YMKMapView new];
[self.mapView setFrame: self.view.frame];
[self.mapView setTracksUserLocation: YES];
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation: YES];
[self.mapView setShowTraffic: NO];
[self.view addSubview: self.mapView];
```

But it seems that setApiKey doesn't work. Any suggestions?